# How many images the DataAugmentation method adds in my dataset? (CNN KERAS)

Tags: python, machine-learning, image-processing, keras, conv-neural-network

I performed data augmentation in my binary CNN. In my original dataset I have 1400 images (700 each class), so, my doubt is when I implement the data augmentation (below) how many images this method adds in my dataset?

```py
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    rotation_range=30,
    zoom_range=0.15,
    featurewise_std_normalization=True,
    width_shift_range=0.2,
    height_shift_range=0.2,
    shear_range=0.15,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode="nearest")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Keras ImageDataGenerator does not *add* images to a dataset, it simply *randomly modifies* images from the dataset as they are needed. Every time you ask it for a batch, it will select several unmodified images from the dataset and then modify them. Because it performs random modifications, it can make a near-infinite number of variations of any given original image.

If you have 1400 images, let's say you get 90% validation accuracy. If you perform augmentations on them, you might get 93%. However, keep in mind that augmentation is not a good substitute for a larger dataset. If you collect 1400 more images, then you might be able to get 95% even without any augmentation. This happens because the new images are entirely new, so they likely have features that cannot be added with standard augmentation.

Comment: So if I have 1400 images in my dataset (performing dataAugmentation) is the same as have 20000 images?  (example)

Comment: @jed1 No, not quite the same. The augmentations can help when you have a small dataset, but they cannot create entirely new images. See my edit for more details.

Comment: Great answer. I have a dataset of 35000 images but only 700 is from one class and the others is from the other class. I take 700 images from the larger dataset to be balanced and write the augmentation in question. There's another option to my problem? I've done the right procedure?

Comment: @jed1 Dealing with imbalanced datasets is a difficult problem that I have little experience with. Taking 700 from the larger class and performing augmentation is an okay solution, and will work just fine if you get the accuracy that you need. However, there are likely more sophisticated techniques you can use that are likely to get you even better results. Unfortunately, I don't know of those techniques. I would suggest reading more articles and/or papers on how to deal with imbalanced datasets.

Comment: @jed1 [This](https://towardsdatascience.com/methods-for-dealing-with-imbalanced-data-5b761be45a18) looks like a good overview. What you're doing right now is basically what is described in section "4. Resampling techniques — Undersample majority class." Happy to have been able to help!